# Issue related to Updating Entity Data Model (.edmx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an asp.net web Application. I have added `Entity Data Model` in the `App_Code` folder, that generates the following files :

1. `Model.Context.tt`
2. `Model.edmx`
3. `Model.tt`

In `Model.tt` there is `Model.cs` file, that contains Partial classes of selected tables.

Now when I try to update the `.edmx` file to add a new table, `Model.cs` is not getting updated, it does not add the new class for newly added table.

How to update `Model.cs` file when any new table or update existing table in `Model.edmx` ?

Thanks

Comment: What **versions** of Entity Framework and Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This issue generally appears when our `.edmx` file is present in a folder in the project. Generally I was able to solve the issue by right clicking the `.edmx` file and then selecting `Run Custom Tool` option. In some cases you will need to do the same for `Context.tt` and `.tt` file also.

In few weird cases when I tried adding/editing columns of an existing table, to update the entity file, I had to open the `.cs` file inside the `.tt` file and then the run `Run Custom Tool` on `.tt` file. It almost worked every time I edited an existing table and entity files were updated successfully.

Hope it helps.